# streamlit survey annotation

Tags: python, user-interface, streamlit

Given a sample file I would like to label certain pairs in streamlit for a survey app, but the code behavior is not what I am expecting:

Here I provide a sample data of ingredients:

```
import streamlit as st
import itertools

ingredients = [
    {'id': 1, 'Food': 'Pizza', 'Type': 'Veggie'},
    {'id': 2, 'Food': 'Meat', 'surname': 'No Veggie'},
    {'id': 3, 'Food': 'Pineaple', 'surname': 'Fruit'},
    {'id': 4, 'Food': 'Pasta', 'surname': 'Veggie'},]
```

I am gathering all answers from users in a `list` from certain pair of ingredients:

```
for i, pair in enumerate(itertools.combinations(ingredients, 2)):
    st.write(pair)

    annotation_result = st.selectbox(f'Do u like? recipe_{i}', options=['Unsure', 'yes', 'no'])
    
    if annotation_result == 'yes':
        l.append([{"Like": [pair]}])
    
    elif annotation_result == "no":
        l.append([{"Disgusting": [pair]}])
        
st.write(l)
```

The expected behavior is that each pair of ingredients should be annotated by a person clicking on the answer. This information is stored in a list.

By default, the for loop iterates through all pairs with same default response, but not waiting, also every decision is printed but nor removed from the prompt, this can be a nightmare when having big data.

In summary, I expect the process to allow clicking, saving, and proceeding to the next pair in a sequential manner with break time for the user. At the end, the annotations can be saved and graphs generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is using mainly the streamlit `session_state` and `Call_back` function to allow allocating correctly the answers. On the other side, the `for` loop has been removed, which wont be so efficient for big data but good enough for this example, so the code functionality work as expected.

```
import streamlit as st
import itertools

def on_button_click(annotation_result, pair):
    if annotation_result == 'yes':
        st.session_state['annotation_list'].append([{'Like': [pair]}]) 
    elif annotation_result == 'no':
        st.session_state['annotation_list'].append([{'Disgusting': [pair]}])

ingredients = [
    {'id': 1, 'Food': 'Pizza', 'Type': 'Veggie'},
    {'id': 2, 'Food': 'Meat', 'surname': 'No Veggie'},
    {'id': 3, 'Food': 'Pineaple', 'surname': 'Fruit'}, 
    {'id': 4, 'Food': 'Pasta', 'surname': 'Veggie'},  
]

if 'annotation_list' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['annotation_list'] = []
    st.session_state['index'] = 0   

pairs = list(itertools.combinations(ingredients, 2))

if st.session_state['index'] < len(pairs):
    pair = pairs[st.session_state['index']]
    
    st.write(pair)

    annotation_result = st.selectbox('Do u like?', options=['Unsure', 'yes', 'no'])

    if st.button('Confirm Selection', on_click=on_button_click, 
        args=(annotation_result, pair)):
        st.session_state['index'] += 1
else:
    st.write(st.session_state['annotation_list'])
```